# Nested Forms error on unknown attribute Id in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, railscasts

I'm attempting the nested forms based on Ryan Bates' #196 Railscasts Nested Forms 1. I'm using `Nested_form` and `Simple_form` gems. Maybe code is competing with gems?

The error that won't seem to go away is

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError at   /surveys/new
unknown attribute: customer_id
```

This occurs when I'm on the `Survey` page and submitting `"New Survey"`.

I've got a `Customer` model and a `Contact` model which are associated to `Survey`.

It's referring to the last line in Survey Controller:

```
def new
   12     @survey = Survey.new
   13     3.times do
   14       customer = @survey.customers.build
   15       2.times { customer.contacts.build }
```

Solutions I tried include doing migrations adding the `CustomerId` to the `Survey` table or the `Customer` table. I've currently removed all references to `customer_id`.

Here's `survey.rb`

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :customers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? } :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :name, :customers_attributes
end
```

Here's `customer.rb`

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :contacts
  attr_accessible :company, :first_name, :last_name, :contacts_attributes, :customer_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? } :allow_destroy => true
end
```

here is `contact.rb`

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mobile_phone, :email
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

and here's my `form.html.haml`

```
= simple_nested_form_for @survey do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.fields_for :customers do |builder|
    = render "customer_fields", :f => builder
    %p= f.submit "Submit"
```

Any help for a newbie?  Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have a customer_id attribute in your contacts table?

Comment: @Tim I don't have any attributes with customer or customer_id in the contacts table

Comment: Well there you go;-) You have to have a customer_id in your contacts table or the customer has_many contacts relationship will not work.

Comment: apparently, time for a migration! @Tim. Thanks - let's see